# UITableView height not according to number of rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview, height

I am designing a `UIView`. In my `UiView`, i have placed a `UITableView` at `(x,y) = (10,186)`. I have set row height to `35` and number of rows to `2`. So technically, the table height should be `70`(or `80` max for a small 2 pix height of header and footer). But unless, i set the table height to `190` in the attributes inspector, it shows only one row. Why does table requires height more than `number or rows * row` height? Is it consuming space somewhere else?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you hadn't set the `UITableViewDelegate` Or are you setting the 
`– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Hi, i am implementing the UITableViewViewDelegate like UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> in the Xib owner file. I have tried to set the height from heightForRowAtIndexPath as well as from the attributes inspector. but nothing seem to work. The main problem is with the designing. The table in UIView in the Xib demands a height of at least 190. I cannot set the remaining elements which are supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Atin UITableView will take the height as u have given it on xib or set its by frame in coding.The only thing you can do is give UItableView less frame in xib so what ever the number of rows it will scroll in that space with no problem and scrolling will be fine..

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I could not figure the solution. Seems to be an issue with Interface builder (Xcode 4.4). Anyways, i added the table from the code itself rather than using it from interface builder.